# how to get DISPLAY variable at the ubuntu login screen?

Tags: xorg, login, xserver

I have a bash script to check user authentication which sets DISPLAY variable as:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xhost +local:
```

After system bootup, at the login screen, this script fails and error is:

**xhost: unable to open display ":0.0"

: cannot connect to X server :0.0**

After login, the same script works but without any error.
So, how to set the DISPLAY variable properly or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

When the system is first booting up, the display is sometimes not available until other background scripts have finished running. My solution is to add a sleep command before your display related commands to give the system time to finish loading. Something like:

```
sleep 5 && export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xhost +local &
```

The '&&'s chain the commands so that they run one after another, and the command following the && will only run if the previous command was successful.  The '&' at the end allows the command to run in the background so that the system can finish loading its necessary components. Without the '&' at the end, the system will not continue loading until the entire line has finished executing, which defeats the purpose of including the `sleep` command.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and get back to you if any problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use that waits for user to sign on:

```bash
SpamLength=1
WaitForSignOn () {

    # eyesome daemon is loaded during boot. The user name is required
    # for xrandr external monitor brightness and gamma control. We must
    # wait until user signs on to get .Xauthority file settings.

    SpamOn=10       # Causes 10 iterations of 2 second sleep
    SpamContext="Login"
    TotalWait=0
    [[ ! -f "$CurrentBrightnessFilename" ]] && rm -f \
            "$CurrentBrightnessFilename"

    # Wait for user to sign on then get Xserver access for xrandr calls
    UserName=""
    while [[ $UserName == "" ]]; do

        sleep "$SpamLength"
        TotalWait=$(( TotalWait + SpamLength ))

        # Find UserName currently logged in.
        UserName="$(who -u | grep -F '(:0)' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $1}')"
    done

    log "Waited $TotalWait seconds for $UserName to login."

    xhost local:root
    export XAUTHORITY="/home/$UserName/.Xauthority"

    if [[ "$fUseDbusMonitor" == true ]] ; then
        echo "$UserName" > "$EyesomeUser"
        sync -d "$EyesomeUser"      # Flush buffer immediately
    fi

} # WaitForSignOn
```